# Accessing current device time in my app

Tags: ios4, nsdateformatter, iphone-4, nstimezone

I want to get current device time in my app,and continuously update that time when my device time is update.i follow that code

```
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yy hh:mm"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString*  todayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I get the current device time,but its not update automatically when user use my app.
what can i do.

Comment: all-caps titles are the less welcome on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The `todayString` has to change as device time changes. That means, you need to create a timer of 60 seconds, and update time for every 60 seconds.

You need to do it like this:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:)
                                                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void) updateTimer:(id) object
{
  // Write required code here.
}
```

Comment: @Shashi Sharma: Did your problem solve using my above solution ?